# Silent/Automated Homebrew Install

Tags: bash, macos, shell, homebrew

I am trying to get homebrew installed remotely on a machine without a terminal open and without ssh access to the machine. Our company uses a Directory-as-a-Service which allows us to remotely push shell scripts to our computers which is great, but it requires the scripts to have no interactivity.

Is there a way to automate the installer and remove the “Press enter to continue” prompt in the install process?

Thanks,
Zach S

Answer (score 2):

The env variable `CI` seems to silence this prompt:
`export CI=1`